# Update params in Ruby on Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller in which I want to update the value of one of the parameters before the update so that the update is carried out in the same save to the database. Unfortunately, the following code does not set `z` in the database:

```
if @model.x == "YES" && @model.z.blank? 
   model_params[:z] = Time.now
end
@model.update_attributes(model_params) 

def model_params
  params.require(:model).permit(:x, :y, :z)
end
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should do it:

```
def update
  attributes = model_params.clone
  if @model.x == "YES" && @model.z.blank?
    attributes[:z] = Time.now
  end
  @model.update_attributes(attributes)
end

def model_params
  params.require(:model).permit(:x, :y, :z)
end
```

You code did not work on the first place because calling `model_params` calls the method, not the actual local variable. You need to create a clone of the returned Hash and use it for the update_attributes.

Comment: You got the first answer in, but you've missed a great opportunity to explain what's happening (you've since edited) or improve the code.

Comment: A safer method in Rails 5, would be to use `update!` as opposed to `update_attributes`. This will cause active record to check for model validations

Comment: `update_attributes` is an alias of `update` and both of them perform the validations (see https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attributes and https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update)